# writing strings to file in a loop puts extra chars at the end of file

Tags: c, gcc

I'm writing some strings to a file, and then i rewind it. This, i am doing in a loop.
Actually, it works just fine, but at the end of the file, it duplicates some chars from the last string. How do i get rid of the extra chars?

So, i have the loop, which writes strings to file, and rewinds it every time at the end of the loop:

> for loop{
>       fputs("string1\n",file);
> fputs("string2\n",file);
> fputs("string3\n",file);
> fputs("stringLAST",file);
> fseek(file,0,SEEK_SET);} //   or  with rewind(file); i get the same result.

As a result my file looks something like this:

> string1
> string2
> string3
> stringLASTstringLASTASTASTSTST

Now, i have the extra chars on the `stringLAST` string. But i need that it looks like this:

> string1
> string2
> string3
> stringLAST

Comment: They are probably left over from a previous run. I see you're seeking & rewinding. If you opened the file for output (deleting or truncating it) immediately before the code listed, it would probably work OK.

Comment: Are you checking for errors?  fputs returns EOF on error. Have you tried flushing the file?  It could be stuff still in the buffer when you rewind.

Comment: yes, i have to truncate it with `ftruncate(fileno(file),0)`. Now, i have to lookup what that means.

Comment: The dirty solution is, to put a extra string filled with spaces to the end of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like to truncate the file to zero length prior to rewriting it, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

  ...
  if (-1 == fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET))
    perror("fseek()");

  if (-1 == ftruncate(fileno(file), 0))
    perror("ftruncate()");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, worked out well, but without the first if-statement. With the first if-statement included, the whole file gets blank.